# Создание базы данных с помощью ODBC-драйвера

Tags: база-данных, windows, sql-server, odbc

Мне нужно ставить инсталлятором вместе с моей программой-сервером базу данных Postgre, я не нашел Merge module для самого Postgre SQL сервера, а нашёл лишь merge module для ODBC драйвера. Можно ли имея только ODBC драйвер создать БД, не имея при этом на машине установленного сервера базы данных?

Comment: «есть только посадочный талон, но нет самолёта. смогу я по нему долететь до рио-де-жанейро?»

Comment: уважаемый @aleksandrbarakin, шутки тут не уместны, тут вопрос в том, есть ли например интерпретатор SQL в драйвере, чтобы можно было создать бд. или с помощью драйвера можно подключиться к удаленному серверу?

Comment: это была не шутка а образное изложение. окей, формальнее: odbc — это программный интерфейс (api) для взаимодействия с системами управления базами данных (субд). если субд у вас нет, то взаимодействовать просто не с чем.

Comment: не совсем понятно для чего это нужно. В качестве источника БД можно использовать и текстовые csv- файлы, и excel-докеументы и т.п. А кому то хватает и расширения для браузера (Chromium/Firefox) на подобие `SQLite Manager`

Comment: @Daemon-5, я обновил вопрос.